# Design of experiment question about 5 varieties of wheat (treatment) and 4 other factors

Tags: experiment-design, design-based-inference

Mr. X wants to compare 5 different varieties of wheat. He has access to a piece of land which has been divided into 25 smaller plots as shown in the figure below. Mr. X has asked for your help in his venture.
[image: Figure:]

(a) Give an allocation of the wheat varieties to the plots so that you're able to compare them. Justify your allocation rule. Clearly state all the assumptions necessary.

(b) Once the crop is harvested how would you analyze the different varieties of wheat?

I'm not sure how to do this question but since there seem to be 5 factors: mountains, river, lake, forest and varieties of wheat, I was thinking that the Hyper Graeco Latin Square Design would be more suitable. However, I'm not sure as to how the allocation should be. Please help/ provide hints.

Comment: This looks a Latin square problem

Comment: @Dave2e but Latin Square Design can control only 2 sources of extraneous variability right? Here we have 4 sources.

Comment: Yes, looking at the diagram 2 blocking factors lake to mountain and river to forest and 1 variable with 5 treatments (seed type).  See https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat503/lesson/4/4.3 for a good into to Latin squares.